# NodeJs/Express writing xlsx-template and sending it back for browser download

Tags: node.js, http, download, client

I have this excel where i want to replace the scalar values as the xlsx-template docs say:

`| Extracted on: | ${extractDate} |`
and I want to send it over the response object. The file gets written correctly in the output path but in the client it gives me a binary output. Bellow is the backend call to the Url

```
this.downloadSheet = async (req, res) => {

    let seriesNumber = Number(req.body.seriesNumber);
    let sheetPath = path.resolve('../filePath/excel.xlsx');
    let sheetFinalOuput = path.resolve('../filePath/excelOutput.xlsx');
    #Get data needed to swap for the excel
    let excelDataStream = await ReportService.getBalanceSheetAllInOne(balanceSheetPath, seriesNumber);
    fs.readFile(path.resolve(balanceSheetPath), function(err, data) {
      // Create a template
      let template = new XlsxTemplate(data);

      // Replacements take place on first sheet
      const sheetNumber = 1;

      // Perform substitution
      template.substitute(sheetNumber, excelDataStream);

      // Get binary data
      var mydata = template.generate({ type: 'nodebuffer'});

      fs.writeFile(path.resolve(balanceSheetFinalOuput), mydata, function(err) {
        if(err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(`Wrote data in file, check please!`);

        // Send File & set headers
        res.set({'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=balanceIncome${seriesNumber}.csv`, 'Content-Type': 'text/csv'});
        res.write(mydata);
        res.end();
      });
    });
  };
```

client function http post request

```
$http.post(`${settings.apiHost}/api/panel/report/balanceSheet/allInOne/false`,{seriesNumber: $scope.seriesNumber})
        .success(function (response) {
          var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'text/csv'});

          var isGoogleChrome = window.chrome != null && window.navigator.vendor === "Google Inc.";
          var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
          var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;


          if (isGoogleChrome){
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

            var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
            downloadLink.attr('href',url.createObjectURL(file));
            downloadLink.attr('target','_self');
            downloadLink.attr('download', `balanceSheet_${$scope.seriesNumber}.csv`);
            downloadLink[0].click();
          }
          else if(isEdge || isIE){
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file,`balanceSheet_${$scope.seriesNumber}.csv`);

          }
          else {
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            window.open(fileURL);
          }
        })
```

Comment: res.write?  res.send is what you need https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send

Comment: I tried that, and I also tried res.sendFile(path.resolve('dataPath.xlsx')); The download file is messed up

Comment: i would change this api to GET method and use window.open to download it, not a blob link. If you must to do this, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/14737423/11303576 to solve response type problem.

Comment: i forgot res.send(buffer) not need send header as a file, delete it to prevent $http.post to decode it, then try convert nodebuffer into arraybuffer, and build blob by the arraybuffer

Comment: Do you mind posting a more concrete example? Or explain a little more on the general process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

client side

```
const url = `${settings.apiHost}/api/panel/report/balanceSheet/allInOne/false/${$scope.seriesNumber}`;
window.open(url);
```

server side(change router params and method to GET)

```
let seriesNumber = Number(req.params.seriesNumber);
... 
fs.writeFile(path.resolve(balanceSheetFinalOuput), mydata, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(`Wrote data in file, check please!`);

  // Send File & set headers
  res.set({'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=balanceIncome${seriesNumber}.csv`, 'Content-Type': 'text/csv'});
  res.send(mydata);
});
```

---

another way

client side

```
...
.success(function (nodeBuffer) {
  let arraybuffer = Uint8Array.from(nodeBuffer).buffer;
  var file = new Blob(arraybuffer, {type: 'text/csv'});
  ....
}
```

server side

```
...
fs.writeFile(path.resolve(balanceSheetFinalOuput), mydata, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(`Wrote data in file, check please!`);
  res.send(mydata);
});
...
```

Comment: The first solution worked like a charm! For some reason, I had different binary output in the excel. Either way, thank you for taking the time and answering. I need the url end point to be secure, for internal authentication. Can I send the http headers with the window object? I think in this case, solution 2 works best. I will try to make it work. Thanks

Comment: no, window.open method don't accept custom header. The solution 2 point is @feecks what you output from server and what you get in browser, does browser can read that buffer? if not, how can make it read, convert to what? how to transform  buffer to blob? that may cost some time to try. hope this tips can help you.

Comment: Thank you this has been of great help!